# What are these words referring to in this sentence: 「咲く場所を厭わない私の体は...」

Tags: meaning, word-choice, interpretation

In One Piece, when Robin reveals her Hana Hana no Mi ability to Pell, she says 咲く場所を厭わない私の体は...あなたを決して逃がさない.

On one hand, I have an idea of what she is saying. I imagine it would be along the lines of "My body that can bloom won't let you go".

However, there are two words that prevent me from understanding this sentence completely.

The main word I have in question is 厭わない. No, translations I've checked cover this word. I know it is similar to hate and that it is a negative conjugation. However, I don't understand what is not being hated here.

The next word is 場所. Most translations I see have this as anywhere. Yet, this does not make sense to me because どこでも seems to be the main way of saying anywhere.

While I somewhat understand this sentence, these two words make it a bit ambiguous for me.

Comment: I would say it’s a misuse of 厭わない, but a rather common one. See what [実用日本語表現辞典](https://www.weblio.jp/content/厭わない) says about 手段を厭わない.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm prefacing this with I know very little about One Piece, but that shouldn't matter all too much. With that being said, let go over things:

First let's talk about 厭わない. This is simply 厭う in the negative form. [厭う](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%8E%AD%E3%81%86) has a lot of meanings, but for the most part it seems to be focused on "disliking the act / the environment of X". So if we negate 厭う, it becomes 厭わない which means something like "not disliking the act / the environment of doing X".

Now let's talk about 場所. [場所](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%A0%B4%E6%89%80) just means place, location, spot, or etc. And it's really no different here if you were translate that sentence in a literal way.

Before we talk about a literal translation, I see you mentioned:

> Most translations I see have this as "anywhere"

This might be difficult to understand what I mean at first, but 場所 is being ***translated*** to "anywhere". At the end of the day, translations are interpretations that attempt to work / make the most sense in the target language. So 場所 as "anywhere", even though it might not really mean anywhere, might be the "best" interpretation for the given context. And 場所 being "anywhere" does make sense under the context of Robin's power. If I remember correctly, her power allows her to grow extra limbs ***anywhere*** on her body.

So with a more literal translation of the whole thing we get:

> 咲く***場所***を***厭わない***私の体は...あなたを決して逃がさない
>
> My body ***does not loath*** the ***spots*** where it blooms... There is no way for you to get away

But this is somewhat odd in English to leave as is. So let's clean it up:

> My body ***doesn't mind*** blooming from ***anywhere***... There is no way you'll get away.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the usage 厭わない is a bit odd here, or could be called wrong.

Given her ability, the meaning should be *I can 'blossom' my hands anywhere, so I won't let you go*, as you have checked in translation.

咲く場所を厭わない would be slightly more naturally どこへでも咲くことを厭わない (*my hands do not hate to blossom wherever it is*). It is assumed that some places are better for 'blossoming' than others and the phrase says any place is not hated (as a place to blossom) despite that.

---

I guess 厭わない is used that way because it is considered as a synonymous to 気にしない. However, since 厭わない rather means *not to avoid*, 咲く場所を厭わない would be mostly unnatural, strictly speaking (avoiding places where blossom happens is just a different thing).